# VBA skipping If statements in Access 2010

Tags: sql, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make it so that when a user selects a person from a combobox their full details are displayed but some error-handling if statements keep giving false when the conditions should be returning true

```
Private Sub ComboOwnerID_Change()
Dim SelID As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim result As String
SelID = 0
SelID = Me.ComboOwnerID.Text
If Not (SelID = 0) Then
    If Not (SelID = Null) Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Owners WHERE OwnerID = " + SelID
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            result = ""
            result = rs!Title + ". "
            result = result + rs!Forname + " "
            result = result + rs!Surname
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        Me.lblOwnerName.Caption = result
    Else
        Me.lblOwnerName.Caption = "error"
    End If
Else
    Me.lblOwnerName.Caption = "error"
End If
End Sub
```

It's not even reached the SQL bit yet so i don't know if that works or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the .text property in VBA, it is only available when the control has focus. The concatenator in VBA is & not +. Using + when one of the strings is null can return null.

```
If Not (SelID = Null) Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
```

You mean:

```
If Not IsNull(SelID) Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
```

Comment: I'd also add that I don't think `SelID` will never be NULL as it is an Integer.

Comment: True, which is going to create a problem if the combo is null. This line will fail `SelID = Me.ComboOwnerID.Text`, quite apart from the .text value.

Comment: To also add to @creamyegg: If `SelID` is an int, then wouldn't `If SelID <> 0 Then` be better than `If Not (SelID = 0) Then` as well?

Comment: @Gaffi I think the problem is in dimensioning selID as an integer. The value of an empty combo is null, so selID should be variant.

Comment: I've actually experimented without the IFs and it works (the + character DOES concatenate)
OK i get IsNull(var) but how would i get the contents of the combo when it's not in focus than as another problem I'm having is that this code isn't being run when i change the record (even if the value is different) as the label needs to update/refresh for the new record.

Comment: + does indeed concatenate but `null + "abc" = null` whereas `null & "abc" = abc`. Do not use the text property for the combo, then the value of the bound column is `Me.MyCombo`, or if you must have a property for religious reasons, use .value `Me.MyCombo.Value` This property is available whether or not the control has focus. The Current event is about the most useful event there is in Access forms.